# Why does the friction at axis of a wheel cause a torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque

To have angular acceleration about the axis, you must have a nonzero torque on the body about the axis of rotation. However, the torque due to the friction at the axis would be zero, since the displacement between the frictional force and the axis is zero. But this still produces a negative angular acceleration. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axis is an imaginary line but the axle of any wheel is a cylinder with a finite radius (R). The frictional force acts on the surface of the cylinder which is at a distance R fom the axis.There is no force on the imaginary object which is the mathematical axis (a line).